# Getting selected text via Safari Extension

Tags: javascript, html, safari, safari-extension

I started learning how to program a Safari extension, and unfortunately Apple's Developer Reference pages on that are not really detailed. Hence my question:

Anyone knows how I can pass the text selected by a user in a variable? My extension is a context menu element that needs to use that text the user selects from any webpage.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

In your injected script, have a statement like the following:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function () {
    safari.self.tab.setContextMenuEventUserInfo(event, window.getSelection());
}, false);
```

Then, in the command handler of your global script, the selection will be accessible as `event.userInfo`, so you can use it, for example, like this:

```
function handleCommand(event) {
    if (event.command == 'myContextMenuCommand') {
        alert('You selected: "' + event.userInfo + '"');
    }
}
```

Comment: My script works until I add this line:
safari.self.tab.setContextMenuEventUserInfo(event, window.getSelection());

Which prevents the script from even moving on to the next statements..

Comment: Try window.getSelection().toString() instead of just window.getSelection().